# Read File with structur, show it and write it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have the following two files (those are language files from a ruby on rails project):

```
en:
  calendar:
    check:
      invalid_date: 'Date is invalid'
      wrong_input_format: "The date should have following format<br/>%{format}"

  globals:
    yestext: "Yes"
    notext: "No"
```

Second File:

```
de:
  calendar:
    check:
      invalid_date: 'Datum ist ungültig'
      wrong_input_format: "Das Datum muss das folgende Format haben <br/>%{format}"

  globals:
    yestext: "Ja"
    notext: "Nein"
```

I need a simple WinForms-Application that shows me the file for editing and saving in a Spreedsheet:

[image]

What is the best way to realize this?

I am a newbie.

Comment: `What is the best way to realize this?` A smart way of *write it for me* :) I don't think you are asking for *best way*.  you can be satisfied with *any way*

Comment: Well, I researched a little bit. Is the best was to deserialize the file? But regarding serialization, I can only find XMLSerializer.

Comment: But I do not have a XML Document.

Comment: Right. Your question is how do I write a custom deserializer more or less, plus how to write an application to use it...

Comment: OK, I will do research about customized deserializer. THX so far

Comment: A customized deserializer is unnecessary for such a simple task; consider @Ferry's suggestion. Also, find out how quotes and apostrophes are encoded in your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is probably:

Build a reader class for the files that is reusable for any number of files (languages) and save it in a `Dictionary<String,<Dictionary<String,String>>`
where it would hold the values: `Dictionary<Language,<Dictionary<Key,Value>>`

Now walk the outer and inner dictionaries and add the items to a table to show. Find the key in first column, if found add to the column you are currently handling. If not found add a new row at the end.

To save changes I would again write a class that takes care of a single file and save all keys that have a value.

I see there are ' and " used. If that is essential save the type. In that case I would not use String for the value, but create a simple class with the value and String sign.

HINT: This would be much easier using a tree for editing the entries.
In that case you don't have to translate the noded design of the original file and visa versa:

Sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23746/TreeView-with-Columns but there are many out there.